# How to parse a multi-lined lambda statement string into DynamicExpression.ParseLambda?

Tags: c#, parsing, dynamic, lambda, expression

I want to pass a multi-statement lambda string (a little program in fact) into `DynamicExpression.ParseLambda` but I fear I may have reached its limitations.  I have written code to feed small lambda expressions but I think it will choke on a full program.

Here is MCVE so far.  It shows the original algorithm BuildSieve() and also it shows the beginning of lambda equivalent but it fails on first line with exception  `Unknown identifier 'long'`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using diag=System.Diagnostics;
using myAlias = System.Linq.Dynamic;   //install package 'System.Linq.Dynamic' v.1.0.7 with NuGet

namespace LambdaStatement
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            BuildSieveLambda();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void BuildSieveLambda()
        {
            try
            {
                var pList = new List<ParameterExpression>();
                pList.Add(Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "x"));
                LambdaExpression e = myAlias.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(pList.ToArray(), null, "long n = 2000000;");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string msg = GetExMessage(ex);
                diag.Debug.WriteLine("DEBUGME: " + msg);
                throw new Exception(msg);

            }
        }

        public static string GetExMessage(Exception ex)
        {
            string ret = ex.Message;
            if (ex.InnerException!=null)
            {
                ret= ret+ ": " + GetExMessage(ex.InnerException);
            }
            return ret;
        }


        static void BuildSieve()
        {

            //https://gist.github.com/gideondsouza/1978926  Sieve of Eratosthenes C# implementation by code Gideon Israel Dsouza

            long n = 2000000;
            bool[] e = new bool[n];//by default they're all false
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
            {
                e[i] = true;//set all numbers to true
            }
            //weed out the non primes by finding mutiples 
            for (int j = 2; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (e[j])//is true
                {
                    for (long p = 2; (p * j) < n; p++)
                    {
                        e[p * j] = false;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

You may think this is impossible but I've seen some really complicated lambda expressions in C# code, full method implementations in fact.  So if the C# compiler or Visual Studio can do this then is there access to that API to programmers?

Comment: MCRE ? What does that mean?

Comment: edited, meant to be minimal complete verifiable example

Comment: Expression tree cannot contain multiple statements, whether you build it with `DynamicExpression` or not.

Comment: @Evk, oh, I am saddened.  but how does compiler do it?

Comment: It doesn't. Try put code from inside `BuildSieve` function into expression tree (not just delegate, but expression tree you are now trying to build) and you will see that you can't. So for example, `Expression<Action<int>> lambda = (x) => ...`

Comment: Lambda expressions and expression trees are different things. `() => ...` is lambda expression, but it can be interpreted differently. It can be interpreted as expression tree, or it can be interpreted as anonymous delegate. You are trying to build expression tree in your code, and such thing can only contain single statement.

Comment: @Evk: ok, so it's not like a full language parser (like some kind of Backus Naur parser), it's just there to help along interplay between Linq-To-Objects and Linq-To-Sql, right?

Comment: Nope it's not. It converts your statement in a tree form (with values like `MemberAccessExpression` and so on), but it's not intended for what you are trying to do. There are tools like Roslyn which can compile arbitrary code at runtime, probably you need that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `n` the same way you added `x`:

```
pList.Add(Expression.Parameter(typeof(long), "n"));
LamdaExpression e = myAlias.DynamicExpression.ParseLamda(pList.ToArray(), null, "n = 200000");
```

Although, I admit, I have no idea what this program does, but this is why you get that error. It is reading `long` in the string as an identifier, instead of a type.

Comment: I'm aware this doesn't solve the overall goal, but it seemed too detailed to put in a comment.